# Depurador de visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Intento depurar el código con **visual studio** pero al ejecutarlo paso por paso me cambia de ventana a una llamada `ostream` y no se que es eso. Se puede depurar el código sin que tenga que pasar por la ventana de `ostream`?
Por ejemplo en este código me hace eso, y en otros IDE no...

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    int N, resultado=0, vector[100];
    cout << "Numero de veces: " << endl;
    cin >> N;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        vector[i] = i + 1;
        resultado = resultado + i;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {

            cout << vector[j];
            if (j != i) {

                cout << "+";
            }
            else {
                cout << "=";
            }
        }
        cout << resultado+vector[i] << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Agrega el código que estás haciendo, se vuelve difícil acertar con pocos datos, al colocar detalles nos será fácil reproducir lo que te está pasando. Saludos :D

Comment: Si estas dando `step-in` entonces va a mostrarte cada paso que pueda, incluyendo llamadas internas, si en algún momento tu código llama a `ostream`, entonces te va a mostrar esa información.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Intento depurar el código con visual studio pero al ejecutarlo paso por paso me cambia de ventana a una llamada ostream y no se que es eso

`ostream` es la clase de `cout`. `cout`, aunque suela pasar desapercibido, es una instancia estática (por eso no hay que *crearla* nunca sino que se puede usar en todo momento). De hecho, en la librería `iostreams` suele estar declarada así:

```
extern std::ostream cout;
```

Pues bien, esta clase tiene sobrecargado el operador de inserción `<<` y, para los tipos básicos, esta sobrecarga suele encontrarse junto con la clase. Me refiero, por ejemplo, a la sobrecarga de `char const*`, como es tu caso:

```
cout << "Numero de veces: " << endl;
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Así pues, si estás depurando y llegas a esta llamada es normal que el depurador salte a la misma... que puede encontrarse en `ostream` o en cualquier otro archivo (dependerá de la implementación de la librería estándar que estés usando). Por supuesto que el depurador puede detectar que la llamada es a la librería estándar y omitir la llamada... al fin y al cabo la librería estándar no contiene código que vayas a modificar.

Y, en serio, lo he dicho mil veces... no es cosa del IDE. El 99% de los problemas de C / C++ **no son culpa del IDE**. El IDE no es más que una aplicación que te facilita la vida... pero el IDE no compila sino que llama al compilador de turno y no depura sino que se comunica con el depurador que toque y te muestra la salida del mismo... el IDE es un mero intermediario.